# sql server select all,selected on xml type

Tags: sql-server

```
Declare @xml = '&lt;root>&lt;row ClassID=''99c24704-bfdb-4350-a35b-102cf5699edb'' UserID=''adsadadsada''  />&lt;row ClassID=''99c24704-bfdb-4350-a35b-102cf5699edb'' UserID=''adsadadsada''  />&lt;/root>'
```

i want to perform the following:-

```
select * from @xml

select classid from @xml

select * from xml where classid=[somevalue]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `*` against XML you need to list the columns you want.

```
Declare @xml xml = 
'<root>
  <row ClassID=''99c24704-bfdb-4350-a35b-102cf5699edb'' UserID=''adsadadsada'' />
  <row ClassID=''99c24704-bfdb-4350-a35b-102cf5699edb'' UserID=''adsadadsada'' />
</root>'

select 
  N.value('@ClassID', 'uniqueidentifier') as ClassID,
  N.value('@UserID', 'varchar(50)') as UserID
from @xml.nodes('root/row') as T(N)
where N.value('@ClassID', 'uniqueidentifier') = '99c24704-bfdb-4350-a35b-102cf5699edb'
```

Comment: thats gr8...thnx a ton Mikael

Answer (score 0):

this syntax is near what you were talking about:

```
;with myXml as
(
select 
  a.value('@ClassID', 'uniqueidentifier') as ClassID,
  a.value('@UserID', 'varchar(50)') as UserID
  from @xml.nodes('root/row') as x(a)
)
select * from myXml
where classid = '99c24704-bfdb-4350-a35b-102cf5699edb'
```